# One-to-many dataframe merges on large sets of data - MemoryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, memory

I have a function that merges 2 dataframes together but repeats the second dataframe for every unique value in the first dataframe.

For example:

```
def one_to_many_merge(left, right):
    return (left.assign(key=1).merge(right.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', 1))
```

It accomplishes this by assigning a key value to the first dataframe and merges that key to the same assigned key for the second dataframe -- then drops that key and repeats.

A small example output for a (3,1) and (2,1) dataframe is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Y' : [10, 20]})

df3 = one_to_many_merge(df1, df2)

df3

X   Y
1   10
1   20
2   10
2   20
3   10
3   20
```

The problem is that I'm running into `MemoryError` for large sets -- it's breaking on merging a `(43262,1)` dataframe with a `(43039,1)` dataframe.

Is there a better way to make this either a parallelized process or something easier for memory to handle when these dataframes become huge? I will be using even larger sets in the future.

Comment: So you want to store 1,861,953,218 rows in memory? Or... are you asking if there's a better way to generate those rows for use in X, Y or Z?

Comment: ```pyspark``` generally should deliver better parallelization than ```pandas```

Comment: Also on a side note: the function name `one_to_many_merge` is a curious choice - what your code does is effectively a many-to-many operation (you're doing what's effectively a "cartesian join" ala "select * from a cross join b" in sql) - could you explain what you're trying to achieve - maybe that'd help solicit viable answers/suggestions?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the above solution output given by `df3` -- essentially repeat `X` for every unique `Y` value.

Comment: Separate your subsequent logic into one or more axes that don't require the entire data set in memory at once. If you can iterate through your `left` rows, just consider one dataframe of size `(1, len(right))` at a time, start there. Further advice requires some information about what you intend to do with that data.